# QGIS Point Features and Labels Not Appearing in .KMZ/Garmin

Tags: qgis, point, export, kmz, garmin

I want to produce a Garmin custom map for use with my Etrex 20x.

I'm working with QGIS 2.14.3-Essen using the GarminCustomMap, version 1.1, plug-in to produce the output .KMZ on a Mac running OS X 10.11.

Issue: The single polygon feature layer appears properly in Google Earth and as a custom map on the Etrex 20x. The several point feature layers do not. None of the layers displays its labels.

Suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure that the point layer is in EPSG:4326? I'm not sure whether labels are converted to KML at all.